# getting exit code of an executed sipp with tcl

Tags: tcl, exec, echo, tshark

I'm trying to get the exit code " echo $? " after executing SIPp command with exec from tcl :

```
if { [catch { exec /usr/local/sipp-3.3.990/sipp -t "u1" -s $SERVICE \
                                -ap $PASSWORD \
                            -sf $SCRIPT_PATH1 \
                            -i $LOCAL_IP \
                            -m 1 -key path $str \
                            -key dnid *20 \
                            -timeout 10s\
                            -trace_err -trace_screen $CLIENT2 -nd | /bin/sh $str/return_code.sh } fid option] }
```

I have tried to do execute "echo $?" but that didn’t work so I tried to execute it from an other script called "return_code.sh"

```
  #!/bin/sh
echo "exit code: $?"
echo "PPID: $PPID"
```

but this also didn't work the result is always 0 , any idea about how to get the exit code from tcl ?

Best regards ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exhaustive example is given at http://wiki.tcl.tk/1039#pagetoce3a5e27b

This might be easier

```
set status [catch {sipp ...} output option]

if {$status == 0} {
    # sipp did not emit anything to stderr, and exited with status 0
} else {
    # some error
    set err_info [lassign [dict get $option -errorcode] err_type]
    switch -exact -- $err_type {
        NONE {
            # sipp exited with status 0 but printed something to stderr
            # which is captured in $output
        }
        CHILDSTATUS {
            # non-zero exit status
            set exit_status [lindex $err_info 1]
            set process_id  [lindex $err_info 0]
        }
        default {
            puts "some other error: $option"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ah I see what you're up to now (your supplied code is way too complicated to demonstrate clearly). You're doing `sipp .... | sh -c 'echo exit code: $?'`. That echo command will always be zero: it is running in a separate process that has not launched any commands. Example:

```
% set status [catch {exec sh -c {exit 42} | sh -c {echo "previous exit status: $?"}} output option]
1
% puts $output
previous exit status: 0
child process exited abnormally
% set option
-code 1 -level 0 -errorcode {CHILDSTATUS 25539 42} -errorinfo {previous exit status: 0
child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"exec sh -c {exit 42} | sh -c {echo "previous exit status: $?"}"} -errorline 1
```

We see that the 2nd sh process's `$?` value is zero. However, the pipeline's exit status, as seen by Tcl, is 42.

Comment: I tried this one but the errorcode returned by tcl is juste NONE , I need to get the result of  **echo $?** in tcl script

Comment: If the errorCode is NONE, the exit status ($? in sh) is zero. You seem to be convinced it is not. Why?

Comment: Because I tried to execute the sipp command (with an error) manually in the terminal and the exit code is set to 1 but with exec command from TCL it always shows NONE. 
I think that TCL is not reading the exit status of sipp as an error so it always shows NONE to errorcode

Comment: No. Example: `set status [catch {exec sh -c {exit 42}} output option]` properly sets the error type as CHILDSTATUS and the exit status as 42.

Comment: Thank you for your support , actually I found an other easier solution by putting addtional informations from sipp in the log file and parsing them later by tcl , this would save me a lot of problems in the futur.